Should I write "a Master of Science degree" or "a master's degree in science" in this case?

Only very small parts of the Malaysian and Singaporean populations hold a [master's degree in science/Master of Science degree].

First, though I know a master's degree in science is correct here, I'm not sure if a Master of Science degree is an alternative to it in this case.
Second, should I write "only very small parts of the Malaysian and Singaporean populations" or "only a small part of the Malaysian and Singaporean population".
Thank you so much in advance!

The exact naming of university degrees is a very strange and archaic part of the English language. It's useful to know, but don't imagine that the details apply to anything else. (It can also vary in the details between countries.)

Master of Science is the title of a degree. Many "Master's" degrees taken in a science subject would lead to an MSc.  But there would be exceptions and edge cases. My own university offered mathematics students free choice in whether to have an MSc or an MA - the course was identical, the only difference was the certificate.
It probably doesn't make any difference in this context.  You can probably assume that, at the accuracy of this data, all Master's degrees are MScs
("Part" or "Parts",  both are reasonable)
The word "Arts" in "Master of Arts" or Magister Artium is not "art" in the sense of painting and sculpture.  "Art" means any skill as a result of learning or practice, and originally included the study of nature that would now be called "science".  It was in contrast to practical skills like being a master carpenter or a master cutler.  A student would become a "master of learning" that is "Magister Artium". Having become a master, the next stage would be to become a teacher, and one qualified to teach other students would be a "Doctor".  As language developed,  "Art" came to mean particularly those skills of painting and sculpture, and "Master of Science" was invented. Later lots of other types of Master's degrees were developed.  But MA is still used for many degrees in subjects like History, Geography, Literature, Economics, Law, Theatre, Philosophy, Architecture and many many others.  The whole classification of "science degrees" is suspect.  Sure Physics is a science degree... But what about Maths?  Psychology? Economics? What about joint degrees "Physics and Economics" or "Physics and Philosophy"? What about education degrees, is a master's degree in "Science education" a science degree?  There are so many questions, all of which are completely irrelevant to the test!

Thank you! One more question. I've noticed that "a PhD in art" and "a Master of Arts" are  more common than "a PhD in arts" and "a Master of Art", at least according to the Ngram. Why is that so?

and at some especially idiosyncratic universities (notably Cambridge University), a person can take a single course and (eventually) end up with both a Master's of Arts and Master's of Science degree (strictly speaking the MA is from the first 3 years, and the MSc from the final year, but all are completed as part of the same course on the same subject)

@KenAdams (1) "Art" and "arts" can mean different things; especially in the case of "PhD in art(s)", "art" suggests that the PhD is in a "traditional" art field (e.g. painting, design, music, acting), while "arts" may suggest a broader field that's "opposed" to sciences. (2) n-gram while helpful can give misleading results, e.g. "a PhD in Art History" will be counted in "a PhD in art".

@JamesK I wouldn't make that assumption at all. There are loads of different Master's degrees (MA, MPhil, MSc, MEng, MPhys, MChem) that could be awarded for science studies.

@xngtng "Arts" are not "opposed" to sciences at all. The sciences are all a subset of the "Arts". "Art" as a subject is not one of the "Arts". Instead it is a "Fine Art".

@OrangeDog In many contexts (see def. 2 in Cambridge Online or 6 in OLD online) they are juxtaposed in contrast, "wrongly" or not, and "a PhD in arts" happens to be a phrase that suggests that usage. I understand your point, hence I put "opposed" in quotes.

@xngtng there isn't really any such thing as a "PhD in Arts", hence the low occurrence. It would be a "Doctor of Arts degree", or "DA". For an actual "Art" doctorate, it would be a DFA.

@OrangeDog Perhaps you cannot get a "PhD in Arts" (there are too many schools in the world to say definitively), and I never suggested it to be the case, but it is easily imaginable to see a sentence such as "A PhD in arts is not as valuable as a PhD in science." (for example, not a statement I agree with.) It is not a common occurrence, the point is n-gram results are not useful due to possible semantic differences and overlaps.

@OrangeDog bad memory on my part, I meant MSci not MSc (obviously the full name is the same, just a different abbreviation)
